# Retrieving digits from a string with a certain pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string value of:

```
"Drop 1.0.2.34 - Compatible with core revision 123456"
```

And I am trying to get the value **1.0.2.34** with the full stops from the string. 
I am using Regex to try and get it, but it returns with a "" value.

Ex.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(string, "([0-9]*[.][0-9]*)*");
if (match.Success)
{
    string version = match.Captures[0].Value;
}
```

I think there is something small that I am missing because it does find a match in the string, but it doesn't have a value. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches an empty string, and since you are only looking for 1 match, it returns the empty string beofre the first char.

Use

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/38OlPq/1)

**Details**:

- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)+` - 1+ sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits.

C#:

```
string version = string.Empty;
Match match = Regex.Match(string, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+");
if (match.Success)
{
    version = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great and thanks for the explanation and details as well!.